# Creating manually remarketing lists with Google Ads is not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I came across a new bug in Google Analytics. It only appears if you create a remarketing list manually and link it to connected Google Ads account. When will it be fixed?

```
Resource is not available. Please try again later.
One or more of the services on which we depend is unavailable. Please try again later after the service has had a chance to recover.
Error ID: 9f51209a-31ee-421b-95c3-d6f82a4112f1
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error returned by the Google Analytics interface on certain occasions detected on the server side.

It is rare but it happens more frequently, for example by querying standard and custom reports. In these cases just try later or decreasing the defined time interval and, if this is not enough, review the dimensions and metrics used in the report: https://www.analyticstraps.com/la-risorsa-non-e-disponibile-riprova-piu-tardi/

In your case, if trying again at a later time the problem persists, what can be done is try to simplify the configuration of the audience you are trying to create.

Comment: Even after 1 day of waiting and reloading the page multiple times, the entire account is bugged. Every time I try to create a remarketing list and click on it, it's the same error. I also tried to create new account for the same email on Google Analytics but with the same error.